# header display issue

Tags: layout, rwd, header, head

Just wondered if anyone knew why the header displays differently on my live site and testing site.(the blue header bar is quite a bit wider and doesnt look as good) The two sites are effectively the same site files, so they should be the same. From what I can tell the only page the live site doesn't do this is the home page.

iartsupplies.co.uk/canvases.html

testingdev.iartsupplies.co.uk/canvases.html

It may well be something to do with the responsive template, but that shouldnt matter as the test site is set up the same way. The same behavior is seen in chrome and firefox. 
I have tried messing about in firebug but cant find anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: `.header h1.logo, .header h3.logo {
    margin: -105px 0 30px;
    padding: 0;
}`  that is difference in both css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some css inconsistencies between the two sites.  For instance, the h3.logo on the site that appears to be correct has the following style applied to it:

```
h1.logo, .header h3.logo {
  margin: -105px 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The h3.logo on the incorrect site does not.   I recommend turning off merging css and js files and recompile any SASS that you might have to see if it corrects your issue on the incorrect site.

Comment: thanks, that worked. I had to disable opti, un merge the cache and purge the cdn.

Answer (score 0):

As Describe by @ TJ Gamble there is issue with your site css files.

Make it same for both sites and clear the cache.